# Is there an easy way to determine where print is being called in python?

Tags: eclipse, python-2.7

The print function is being called and I need to find out where it is coming from. Since Eclipse's ctrl + H is really slow (for me on a project of this size) and I'd rather not use a traditional method of stepping through the debugger on such a large project, I was wondering if there is any easy way to determine where the print function is being called.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

What about using `grep` on Unix-like systems:

```
grep -F -R "print" /path/to/your/python/code/base/
```